# Where is said how do you get the NUMLOCK key to default to on for the GUI console?

Tags: fedora, man, info

This is on a fedora machine.
I have to look in man pages first to find the answer, if not then in an info page. If the answer is not there then I have to use the internet to find the answer. It is on a school server. I thought it was numlockx but that program is not installed on the server and it is suppose to be something that is on the server. I don't know of any other program that it could be.

Comment: "GUI" and "console" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That is how the professor wrote the question. I am actually confused on it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - no, they're not.  "console" is generic

Comment: @CraigSanders: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console

Comment: I know what a Linux Console is.  the very fact that the word needs to be prefaced with the type of console (e.g. text console, linux console, serial console, audio engineer's console, lighting console, nukular power-station console, 
etc etc etc) just highlights the fact that "console" itself is generic.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious answer would be

```
apropos numlock
```

but on my system this only mentions `numlockx`. This is the normal way of setting Num Lock programmatically under X.

Another lead is that Num Lock is a LED.

```
apropos leds
```

This turns up [setleds](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_setleds.htm), which allows setting Num Lock programmatically, but only outside X.

I would answer “install numlockx, and run `numlockx on` as part of the session start”.

Answer (score 0):

System Settings -> Keyboard & Mouse (or input devices) -> Keyboard -> Num lock on KDE Startup -> Turn On